# Difference between Redis max-wait and timeout

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-session

I can see two properties in my spring boot application. Which uses Redis for session storage

- spring.redis.jedis.pool.max-wait
- spring.redis.timeout

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1):

From the Spring Boot [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data):

- `spring.redis.jedis.pool.max-wait`: Maximum amount of time a connection allocation should block before throwing an exception when the pool is exhausted.
- `spring.redis.timeout`: Read timeout.

Since you mention session storage, you may also want to be aware of `spring.session.timeout` which configures the session timeout.